# How to get WAMP to work with MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, wamp

I have installed SQL Server 12 and WAMP(64 bit). I wan to connect MSSQL to WAMP. I found this links
https://forum.ragezone.com/f724/wamp-mssql-673301/
 Is this the best way to configure it ?

Comment: Probably not thats a bit old. As far as I remember the MSSQL extension is only available as a 32 bit extension, so you may want to start by uninstalling WAMPServer 64bit and installing the 32bit version. There is no benefit in the 64bit version and in fact like this situation it just makes using some of the more unusual extensions more difficult. Hopefully this will change when PHP7 is a true 64bit port, unlike all previous versions which are still considered _experimental_